# pandas groupby sum takes to long, how can I optimize this?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of around 2 million rows. If I do this groupby

```
 df = df.groupby(by=['country','os','device'], as_index=False)
```

It only takes a short time. But if I do:

```
 df = df.groupby(by=['country','os','device'], as_index=False).sum()
```

It takes forever and I have to kill the script.

This started when I updated from Pandas 17 to 20.

Why is this happening and how can I rewrite it so it works fast again?

EDIT:

```
   nl,windows,c,awdo2323fa3rj90
   uk,mac,c, awdawdoj93di303
   nl,ios,m, aawd9efri403
   nl,ios,m, 39fnsefwfpiw3r
```

[country,os,device,md5_id]
output should be

```
   nl,windows,c
   uk,mac,c
   nl,ios,m
```

Like EdChum said the groupby returns groupby object so I added sum() and this worked in pandas 17, but I think this is now in 20 causing a problem, because there are no numeric columns.

Comment: `groupby` by itself is just an object describing how to perform the grouping so it's just metadata, when you actually perform some aggregation on the object is when it does any real work. Do you have mixed dtypes in the columns or missing values in the groupby columns?

Comment: @EdChum I checked there is no missing data and all columns are objects. So maybe the sum() operation isn't correct anymore on Pandas 20? I have 4 columns with strings and I want to have the unique values of 3 columns (country,os,device)

Comment: Sorry you're trying to `sum` columns that are not numeric? Can you post some sample raw data that is representative and the desired output

Comment: @EdChum I added some extra info.

Comment: All you seem to be doing is just removing the duplicates based on the first three columns, is that what you want? if so you can just do `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['country','os','device'])`

Comment: @EdChum you are right, I just found the same thing. I didn't know about the drop_duplicates function. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer some of your queries, a `groupby` object is just metadata, it describes how to perform the grouping, it only does some work when you call some aggregation  function on it, as you have no numerical columns I'm not sure what you're expecting by calling `sum`.

It looks like all you want is to [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['country','os','device'])
```

So that what is left are non-repeated rows based on the passed `subset` of columns